# Accessing non-Google APIs using oauth2client library

Tags: python, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I am trying to evaluate the usage of `oauth2client` and `oauth2` libraries on Python. We have already installed the former on our server for using some Google API.

Now I am trying to find out a way to use the same library to use external API too. I was trying to find an example to do so. However, as I read in most of the sources online, the `oauth2client` is predominantly for Google APIs.

The idea behind this trial is to see if we can do away with this requirement without installing `oauth2` package on our server(s).

Any `oauth2` and security experts may please guide me properly, as I could not find in the `oauth2client` documentation that this package is not supported for any external APIs using oauth for authentication.

https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/# This says..

> `oauth2client` makes it easy to interact with OAuth2-protected
>   resources, **especially** those related to Google APIs

I am running on Python and I have `key`, `secret` and the `url` on which I can go a `GET` to get the required API I need. Please advise.

Comment: You could probably inherit from the classes in oauth2client to work with other resources.